# Deadlock in C++ code

Tags: c++, qt, concurrency, deadlock

I try to handle a deadlock in my code but I can't fugure out how to prevent it. I have a thread which accesses data and an update method which update the data. The code looks like this:

```
thread {
    forever {
        if (Running) {
            LOCK
                access data
            UNLOCK
        }
         Running = false;
    }
}

update {
    Running = false;

    LOCK
        access data
    UNLOCK

    Running = true;
}
```

I tried to fix it with a second access variable but it doesn't change anything.

```
thread {
    forever {
        if (!Updating) {
            if (Running) {
                LOCK
                     access data
                UNLOCK
            }
        }
         Running = false;
    }
}

update {
    Updating = true;
    Running = false;

    LOCK
        access data
    UNLOCK

    Updating = false;
    Running = true;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**
This is a better description of the problem:

```
thread {
    forever {
        if (Running) {
            LOCK
                if (!Running) leave
                access data
            UNLOCK
        }
        Running = false;
    }
}

update {
    Running = false;

    LOCK
        access data
    UNLOCK

    Running = true;
}
```

My update function is a bit more complex, so that I can't see a way to use one of the standard algorithm for this.

**UPDATE 2**
Here is the simplified c++ source code. maybe it's better to read as the pseudocode:

```
void run() {
    forever {
        if (mRunning) {

            QMutexLocker locker(&mMutex);
            for (int i; i < 10; i++) {
                qDebug("run %d", i);
                sleep(1);
                if (!mRunning) break;
            }

            mRunning = false;
        }
    }
}

void update() {
    mRunning = false;

    QMutexLocker locker(&mMutex);

    qDebug("update");

    mRunning = true;
}
```

**UPDATE 3**
Ok. The problem is a bit more complex. I forgot that my accesss data part in the thread starts also some child threads to fill the data structure

```
datathread {
    access data
}

thread {
    forever {
        if (Running) {
            LOCK
                if (!Running) leave

                forloop
                    start datathread to fill data to accessdata list
            UNLOCK
        }
        Running = false;
    }
}

update {
    Running = false;

    LOCK
        access data
    UNLOCK

    Running = true;
}
```

Comment: [Wikipedia article on mutual exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion)

Comment: Thanks. I have read this article and also googled for it.

Comment: If I put in my first example a `sleep(1)` behind my forever loop everything works like excepted.

Comment: Then use the links in the article to have a look at the various mutual exclusion algorithm articles (e.g. Dekker's, Szymanski's, etc) where you'll learn that using a single variable does not provide a solution to the mutual exclusion problem. In modern systems mutex's and semaphore's should be provided by the OS - I suggest you use one of these. If you feel the need to roll your own, try starting with the simplest of these algorithms (arguably [Dekker's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekker%27s_algorithm)), implement it, and use it. Best of luck.

Comment: My scond atempt is based on Peterson's. It would be nice to understand there exactly the deadlock happens.

Comment: @adapto `Updating = true;` and `Updating = false;` should be atomic operations as well. Probably the same is needed for the `Running` state.

Comment: Thanks πάντα ῥεῖ but this didn't fix it. The problem is, that I can't use a standard algorithm because my second function enters only once and is not a endless loop. And the second problem is, that I want to leave function one then function 2 is entered.

Comment: Please update your post with additional information. What software behavior do you mean when you say it is deadlocking?  What is the software doing and what do you expect it to do?  And what is the architecture of the software and how is the function `update()` being invoked?

Comment: Your (pseudo)code is still not clear. You should add the part where you `access data`. How and what kind of data? If I had to guess, you should limit the life time of your `QMutexLocker`

Comment: Deadlock is impossible in the code which uses single mutex (except cases when you attempt to take a lock in the code which already has it). What is your problem exactly?

Comment: In access data data is a vector which is filled with web content accessed through QNetworkRequest and an event loop. Maybe this is the problem. At this point a new thread is started. And the update function should cancel the downloader und fill it with new access information.

Answer (score 0):

Standard way for *read* method being restarted when during *write* is to use *seqlock*. With single *writer* and *reader* seqlock is just atomic integer variable, which is incremented every time when writer is started and when it is ended. Such a way *reader* method can periodically check whether variable is unchanged since *read* is started:

```
atomic<int> seq = 0;

updater() // *writer*
{
    seq = seq + 1;
    <update data>
    seq = seq + 1;
}

thread() // *reader*
{
     retry: // Start point of unmodified data processing.
     {
         int seq_old = seq;
         if(seq_old & 1)
         {
              // odd value of the counter means that updater is in progress
              goto retry;
         }

         for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         {
             <process data[i]>
             if(seq_old != seq)
             {
                 // updater has been started. Restart processing.
                 goto retry;
             }
         }
         // Data processing is done.
     }
}
```

If several updater() can be executed concurrently, whole `update` code should be executed with mutex taken:

```
updater() // *writer*
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&updater_Mutex);

    seq = seq + 1;
    <update data>
    seq = seq + 1;
}
```

If even single element of data cannot be accessed concurrently with updating, both `<update data>` and `<process data[i]>` should be executed with mutex taken.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But it doesn't help to fix my problem. I think I will need to add some thread counter. Like I explained in my third update the loop starts seperated threads and you dont know which of them finished right now and how many threads are in progress. Thats the reason why I can't finish the loop. I didn't saw this before but now I'm sure that this construction makes it imposibel to use this standard methods. If you use such a switch you can control only one thread.

Comment: I think I have to count the started threads and then I need to wait still all started threads are finished before I can leave the loop.

Comment: You should wait all started threads in any case, even if no `update()` call occures during their execution. From the other side, these threads can also check `seq` counter and terminate downloading if counter has been changed.